# Запуск java-приложения с корректными параметрами с помощью терминала

Tags: java, linux, spring, jar, command-line-interface

Всем привет. Пытаюсь запустить приложение, оно находится тут  /home/admin/github-cli-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. Выполняю в терминале команду `java -jar github-cli-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Приложение стартует, но до конца не запускается и в конце выводится следующее сообщение:

> 2021-10-01 06:46:06.450  INFO 9248 --- [           main] c.example.demo.GitHubClientApplication   : Cannot connect to 'null'. Check the address is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ты делаешь тестовое задание на курс по DevOps от Яндекс.Практикума.

Я сделал следующее:

1. Посмотрел процессы джавы:

   ```
   ps -ax
   ```
2. Увидел это:

   ```
   java -jar /home/admin/github-cli-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --GITHUB_ADDRESS=https://gitbub.com
   ```
3. Исправил ошибку в слове github и перезапустил

   ```
   java -jar /home/admin/github-cli-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --GITHUB_ADDRESS=https://github.com
   ```